# What is occurring in this .htaccess file in regards to rewriting to clean URLs?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code in my *.htaccess* file, which is working fine and using "pretty" permalinks to reroute everything back to `/index.php`, and using `$_GET` values to serve customized content based which URL was requested.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([-\w.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

I'm just trying to get an understanding of how this code is working:

I get that the two *RewriteCond's* are there to avoid this behavior in the case that someone is requesting an actual file or directory. But my question involves how removing those two *RewriteCond's* causes a different error. If they are removed, and I request `example.com/register`, is the browser is redirected to:

`example.com/index.php?page=index.php`.

I can't see how these two things are related, so I was just wondering if anyone could explain why this happens? (I have `R=302` set just for now so I can see where it's redirecting me to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pseudo-code translation of your *.htaccess* file would be something along these lines:

- Line 1: In case we weren't previously planning to do anything special with URLs, we are now (*RewriteEngine* is an optional processing module and we're making sure its enabled).
- Line 2: When we're talking about rewrite URLs, from here on append the path `/` to the beginning of the URL, which in your case means on line 6 your rewrite URL would become: `/index.php?page=$1`.
- Lines 4-5:

  - `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is a special server variable containing full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request.
  - The `-d` switch is a test with a boolean result value, that returns true if the preceding value is an existing directory.
  - The `-f` switch is a test that returns true if the preceding value is an existing file.
  - The exclamation mark (`!`) is equivalent to the logic word **NOT**.

So in this instance, lines 4-5 are checking for the current request to make sure we're not referring to an existing file or directory, and then proceeding to execute the *RewriteRule* on line 6. If the conditions on lines 4 and 5 are not both true, then line 6 would be skipped.

- Line 6: The string `^([-\w.]+)$` is a regular expression:

  - A dash (`-`) as the very first or very last character in the square brackets will be interpreted as a literal dash and not as a range instruction.
  - The backslash and w (`\w`) is a shorthand character class or (see "Generic Character Types" in the [PCRE Manual](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)), where the "w" is short for "any word character" - defined in the manual as "an underscore or any character that is a letter or digit" and therefore equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.
  - A dot (`.`) inside the character class is simply a literal dot.
  - A plus (`+`) is one or more occurrences of whats inside the brackets `[ ]`.

Now to summarize then on line 6:

If the request URL includes at least one occurrence of a hyphen `-` followed by any an alphanumeric or underscore character, then the *RewriteRule* will apply and change the URL to append the requested URL to `index.php` as a query string parameter named `page` for the purposes of further processing through your *.htaccess* file. From inside your `index.php` PHP script you would be able to access this value using `$_GET['page']`.

By specifying a 302 redirect (`R=302`) however, this will trigger an `HTTP 302` response and redirect the user's browser to this URL rather than keeping the *RewriteRule* a secret internal operation.

The `L` tells Apache this is the last rule to follow, and the rest of the *.htaccess* will now be ignored.

The `QSA` stands for *Query-String-Append* and tells Apache to add the page parameter to the existing query parameters, which otherwise would be replaced by default.

For more information about understanding regular expressions, see [this](http://www.ladadadada.net/articles/apache_regex_guide). You can find detailed documentation for Apache's `mod_rewrite` module [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). And a guide with some useful examples [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

*Credit to MrWhite for corrections regarding `\w`*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Very detailed and it explained a lot. I did know about the R=302 flag, I just had it set that way temporarily so I could see where it was being rewritten/rerouted. The links are great too, especially the last one. Thanks again.

Comment: Nicely detailed explanation (have a look at the edits for some formatting tips).

Comment: `^([-\w.]+)$` - A couple corrections to the interpretation of this regex... `\w` is not a literal `w`. `\w` is a _shorthand character class_ representing `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Yes, this can itself be used inside a character class. And a dot (`.`) _inside a character class_ is a literal dot, not any character. This regex is therefore equivalent to `^([-A-Za-z0-9_.]+)$`. This means the following sentence is incorrect, "If the request URL includes `-w` followed by any other character" - characters inside a character class do not determine _order_.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite, I've now updated my answer taking into account your corrections. I learnt something new today :)